# Can't view or edit tempdb in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a database on Azure using the SQL Database (PaaS) offering.

I can't see or access the **tempdb** nor can I create it.

[image: Azure SQL Database view]

If I try to create the database I get the following error:

```
Msg 1801, Level 16, State 3, Line 10
Database 'tempdb' already exists. Choose a different database name.
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

TempDB on Azure SQL Database is created and managed by Azure platform and the TempDB capacity has a limit in size based on the Azure SQL Database tier.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to up tick Alberto since he is right about the service handling this system database.

**I guess my main question is why are you using [tempdb]?**

Before there was a push to the cloud, lazy SQL developers would create tables in [tempdb].  These tables should have been placed into a user defined staging database or schema.

Let's see if local/global temporary tables and user defined tables in [tempdb] are allowed.

```
-- local temp table
select 'Fee Fie Foo Fumb' as rhymes into #a
go

-- show the data
select * from #a
go

-- show my local tables
select * from tempdb.sys.tables
go
```

The expected results are shown below.  Local and global temp tables are supported.

[image]

If we try the following create statement within Azure SQL database, the service is smart enough to know that you can not use [tempdb] directly.

[image]

Now, back to my first question.

**Why are you trying to use and/or modify [tempdb]??**

Comment: Adding to your reply I would like to share with all some special behavior of temporary tables on Azure SQL Database. http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0013.htm

Comment: When is the last time you tested Azure SQL database and global temporary tables?  (:)->-< My test shows they work.  The cloud is a moving target.  You always have to catch up since you are behind the last code release.

Answer (score 0):

In rebuttal to Alberto, global temporary tables are now supported in Azure.  The database being referenced by the session is a Basic tier (b0) level.

[image]